# Two column mode does not give columns of exactly the same height

Tags: two-column, vertical-spacing

Sometimes latex does not care that two columns be of exactly the same height. Here is an example, where on the first page the left column is about a millimeter longer than the right one:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Is the problem caused by the fixed paragraph space lengths? If yes, how to reduce/enlarge them but still have the vertical stretching working?

Comment: The default for twocolumn is `\flushbottom` so vertical stretch space will stretch so the columns have equal last baselines. If you are not seeing that then if you show an example someone can debug. Otherwise not really possible to guess an answer to your question.

Comment: the standard two column mechanism does not balance the columns it always fills the left hand column first (unlike, say, `multicol` package columns) so I do not understand your comment about balancing above.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX uses `\flushbottom` by default in twocolum, so that any stretchabke vertical space is stretched so that the baselines of the last row in each column  line up.

In your example though you have removed all stretchable space, setting `parskip` to a fixed 6pt, and having no section headings or display math on the page means that  there is no space that can be stretched. as `\parskip` is not a multiple of `\baselineskip` the columns are necessarily of different lengths as they have different numbers of paragraph breaks.

You could use

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

if you want all lines to line up:

[image]

Although that still has no stretchable space to account for any items that are of different heights.

Or use a flexible `\parskip` such as

```
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt}
```

[image]